# Why is the minimum voltage not -Vcc?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

So for the following circuit, the lowest the output voltage is -Vcc + Vce(sat) according to my textbook. However why can't we assume a lower value than Vce(sat) at the collector-emitter junction of Q2? Is it because the current mirror would not work at a collector-emitter voltage less than Vce(sat)?

[image: amplifier]

Comment: Do you understand what \$V_{ce(sat)}\$ *is*?

Comment: Vce(sat) is the minimum voltage possible between collector-emitter. It cannot turn on/conduct any better to get it lower. It is not even acting as an amp anymore at that point. It is acting as the best closed switch it can be.

Comment: Vce(sat) is the voltage beyond which there is no increase in collector current

Comment: @DKNguyen If I go below Vce(sat), I should be able to conduct provided I don't go to zero.

Comment: You clearly do not understand what Vce(sat) is. How can it decrease without a further increase in collector current? Replace Q2 collector-emitter with a diode. Tell me how you think you can reduce the diode voltage drop without increasing current?

Comment: Your definition of Vce(sat) is also wrong.

Comment: @DKNguyen Would it be correct to say if the current mirror were not to operate in the active region, the entire circuit would not be a linear amplifier?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change the fact you still can't get lower than Vce(sat) in that circuit, even if you don't care whether it is an amp or not. It literally cannot go lower. Not that if it does go lower then it stops being a linear amp.

Comment: Ignoring the definition for now, apart from superconductors you cannot get zero volts across a conducting element. The transistor will have *some* effective resistance between collector and emitter and \$V_{ce(sat)}\$ is \$I_{ce} * R_{ce}\$ (to a very close approximation) and can never be zero.

Comment: @cojoye, if you applied a voltage source as the output load, you could make the output voltage lower.

Comment: Vcesat is BY DEFINITION the lowest voltage that a fully turned on CE junction can assume. You can pull the C lower by some external means, but that's irrelevant here. Your answer "Vcc- + Vcesat" translates to "The lowest negative voltage available PLUS the smallest possible Vce value in this situation". If you can get lower then 2 x Lowest-possible values then something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vcesat is **BY DEFINITION** the lowest voltage that a fully turned on CE junction can assume. You CANNOT get a lower Vce voltage BECAUSE you have defined this as the lowest voltage possible. That is what sat (= saturated) means. = turned as on as it is able to be in this context.

You can pull the Collector lower by some external or independent means, but that's irrelevant here. Here the mechanism of lowering Vout is by reducing Vce - and you have defined how low that can be by defining a value called Vcesat.

So

Your answer "Vcc- + Vcesat" translates to

- "The lowest negative voltage available

PLUS

- The smallest possible Vce value in this situation".

If you can get lower then 2 x Lowest-possible values then something is wrong.